# how to change bootstrap tr class when tables value is changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, slim-lang

I got bootstrap table

```
  table.table.table-striped.table-bordered
    thead
      th Test name
      th status
      th error message
      th

    tbody
      - @testrun.testcase.reject(&:empty?).each do |i|
        tr class=["" ]
          td = "#{i}"
          td = @testrun.testcases_output["#{i}"]["status"]
          td = @testrun.testcases_output["#{i}"]["error_message"]
          td
            a href='/log'
              | log
```

testcase statuses changes through test run from "In queue" to "Success" or "Failed". And I need to change `tr` class to danger/success/primary, when statuses is change. There is any way how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a posssible solution

```
  - @testrun.testcase.reject(&:empty?).each do |i|
    - trClass = ""
    - trClass = "danger" if @testrun.testcases_output["#{i}"]["status"]=="Failed"
    - trClass = "success" if @testrun.testcases_output["#{i}"]["status"]=="Success"
    tr{class: trClass} 
      td = "#{i}"
```